# Animation in ListView item doesn't work after scrolling

Tags: android

I have animation in one listview item. After scrolling list when list item with animation started not visible I am scrolling back to the listview item with animation but animation doesn't work anymore.

```
getView() method :

iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim);
iv.requestFocus();              
((AnimationDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).start();
```

?

UPDATE:

Is it wrong question or there are not any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that every time the view is been scrolled(or become visible to you), the animation will start playing. But it's not true, the view can be not visible an yet be in the memory, so when you are scrolling it and it become visible, the getView() method will not be called. This is why it is a bad practice to put animations inside a list. I suggest you to implement the entire view by yourself if this is something you most to do.

Comment: Your explanation is accurate, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't use animations in list items. Lots of apps do this very effectively: you just need to understand how `ListView` manages the list items.

Comment: @DanHulme But how do you solve the problem on when to start playing the animation? Except the cases when your animation is randomly starts or always playing.